# KendoUI treeview: remote data issue

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-treeview

I have a KendoTreeview. I am using MVC4 and the latest from KendoUI.
I am also using sql server and C#

Let's say I have a database called "MyDB" and a single table in that database called "Products".

Table "Products":
ID -- int -- pk
Name -- nvarchar(50)
Parent -- int -- FK

I want to have a product have sub products...

Ok, now in the controller I have:

```
 public JsonResult ProductsForTreeView(int? id)
    {
         var dataContext = new ProductsDBContext();
         var products = from e in dataContext.Products
               where (  id.HasValue ? e.Parent == id : e.Parent == 0) 
               select new
                          {
                              id = e.Id,
                              Name = e.Name,
                              hasChildren = e.Id
                          };

 return Json(products , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

And the view:

```
@(Html.Kendo().TreeView()
      .Name("treeview")
      .DataTextField("Name")
      .HighlightPath(true)
      .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                                    .Read(read => read
                                                      .Action("ProductsForTreeView", "SiteMap")
                                    )
      )
    )
```

This works and displays the treeview correctly(ALMOST!) except that the treeview is displaying the + next to every node... regardless of whether it has children or not.

Either I need to modify my LINQ or maybe even use some JavaScript to remove the "+"'s where there are no child elements...

The class name for the "+" is "k-icon k-plus".

How can I stop the treeview from appending this "+" to every node? It should only be displayed to nodes that have children.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is your returning **JSON**. It will add the expand('+') icon if your ***.hasChildren*** property is set to **true**.

So your ***.hasChildren*** property should have a boolean value that says true **only if** that node has child/children. In your case, you used ***e.Id*** which I think is not a boolean.

Try this:

```
hasChildren = e.Products.Any()
```

Or check out their documentation.
http://demos.kendoui.com/web/treeview/remote-data.html

Hope this helps.